# Get LinkedIn User's Connections API

Tags: linkedin-api

I am developing an app that will require the connections of the users logged into my app using LinkedIn. Is it possible, without or even through any Partner Program, that i can fetch all the connections(1st Degree) of the current user?
If any, please share the details with me. Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Thank You.

## linkedin

Comment: It seems they have stopped it : https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes . Also the possibilities of their partner programs are not quite clear.